# HTML whitespace: spaces before and after <br>

Tags: html, css, whitespace, language-lawyer

I am trying to better understand the HTML whitespace processing model. Right now I'm comparing two HTML snippets:

```
<div>a <br>z</div>
```

and

```
<div>a<br> z</div>
```

The first snippet, when renered, yields two lines: `"a "` and `"z"` (So the first line has a trailing space.)

The second snippet yields two lines: `"a"` and `"z"`. There is no leading space on the second line.

My question is: why? I'm currently using this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model as a reference. It states

> 1. If a space (U+0020) at the beginning of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is removed.
> 2. All tabs (U+0009) are rendered as a horizontal shift that lines up the start edge of the next glyph with the next tab stop. Tab stops occur at points that are multiples of 8 times the width of a space (U+0020) rendered in the block's font from the block's starting content edge.
> 3. If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is also removed.
> 4. If spaces (U+0020) or tabs (U+0009) at the end of a line have 'white-space' set to 'pre-wrap', UAs may visually collapse them.

A naive reading of this would indicate that, since a space that the beginning *or* end of a line is to be removed (when 'white-space' is 'normal'), the first of my snippets ought to result in no trailing space. But that isn't the case.

So what's going on?

My current theory is that the `<br>` is secretly counted as a "character" which, in the first snippet, prevents the trailing space from being at the "end" of its line. But I really have no idea.

EDIT: To be clear, I know how to use `&nbsp;` to create spaces at will. My question is about what rule (with regard to some spec) induces the above behavior.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#white-space-phase-1, the current spec, might provide some insights

Comment: @Vucko: That's how it appears in the DOM inspector, not how it's rendered.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: Good grief. The amount of jargon in css-text makes the CSS2.1 text read like a children's book.

Comment: @BoltClock true, my bad - I've misread the OP.

Comment: @BoltClock The current (modern) CSS specs are technical specs targeted toward (optimized for) UA/browser implementors. They’re written with a lot more rigor and precision than the CSS2-era specs, and intended to be completely unambiguous—such that any two implementors following the spec requirements will end with exactly the same result, such that we get true interoperability for CSS among all UAs/browsers as a result. One consequence is, the specs need to define a lot of terms, and make reference to a lot of those. Which can look like an excessive jargon but is generally necessary in context.

Comment: @BoltClock Also in general you probably want to avoid reading https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ at all and pretend it doesn’t exist. It’s mostly just of historical interest at this point. For anything CSS, the place to get the right specs to read is https://drafts.csswg.org/ Also a good place to ask questions about this stuff is the #whatwg channel or irc.freenode.net.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: I suppose it is time. For the past few years I've maintained that unless a css3 spec has interop it's better to refer to the more stable CSS2 recommendation, especially if there are breaking changes (though those are few and far between).

Comment: @BoltClock So it turns out you may have found a bug in the spec https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Sep/0077.html Either that or browsers need to change behavior to match what the spec says.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: That would be the OP, not me ;) Interesting case nonetheless.

Comment: @BoltClock ah true. So, kudos to the OP for finding it

Answer (score 2):

Good question! I've confirmed the behavior in both Chrome and Firefox, and confirmed that it has nothing to do with `<br>`, as it's also triggered by an ordinary linebreak in `white-space: pre-line` conditions:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-line">a 
z</div>
```

I've [sent an email to the list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Sep/0077.html) asking for clarification on this issue, and inquiring whether we should change the spec to match implementations, or file bugs on browsers to match the spec.